# How to make video Black and white without effecting other elements and deformations in Spark Ar

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I have my filter ready, with some face paint materials added and some deformations to increase the eye size.  Everything is looking good, but now I want to turn the users video black and white.

I have tried doing it with camera textures as explain in one of the spark AR demonstrations (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio/tutorials-and-samples/samples/glasses-advanced/#using-the-camera-texture). But this effects all my masks, and hides my facial distortions.

Does anyone know a way to turn the video black and white, without effecting the face tracking manipulations?

Answer (score 0):

I’m with you. I know the problem: we’re performing changes on the camera texture and returning the texture itself that will completely cover the image we’re translating to the phone. So here are two theoretical solutions applicable:
1. After performing the color changes we should somehow override the camera texture
2. We should feed already edited texture (with face distortion) to the module that consumed the default camera texture.

Let me know if you found any practical solution for one of the options listed above or you found any alternate way.

Regards